# How to configure HHVM with Nginx compiled from source?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, hhvm

I installed Nginx 1.8 (compiled from source) on Debian 7:

```
cd /opt/
sudo wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz
sudo wget http://labs.frickle.com/files/ngx_cache_purge-2.3.tar.gz
sudo tar -zxvf nginx-1.8.0.tar.gz
sudo tar -zxzf ngx_cache_purge-2.3.tar.gz
cd /opt/nginx-1.8.0/

sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-ipv6 --add-module=/tmp/ngx_cache_purge-2.3

sudo make && make install
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --disabled-password --group nginx 

sudo wget -O init-deb.sh http://www.linode.com/docs/assets/1538-init-deb.sh
sudo mv init-deb.sh /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults
```

Than I start nginx with the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

And everything works fine until now.

The problem is when I try to install HHVM it doesn't work:

```
sudo wget -O - http://dl.hhvm.com/conf/hhvm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/debian wheezy main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hhvm libgmp-dev libmemcached-dev
sudo update-rc.d hhvm defaults
```

And when I finally run:

```
sudo /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
Checking if Nginx is installed
Nginx not found
```

Any thoughts how I can install HHVM with Nginx compiled from source?

Comment: Debian is based on packages. By compiling your own stuff outside the package management system you are in unsupported (and unsupportable) land.

Comment: What do you suggest? Can I move to other Linux Distribution?

Comment: No, install NGinx from Debian repository. Is there a reason why you compiled NGinx from source ?

Comment: Because the one from repository is version 1.2.1 which is like 3 years old, the one I compiled is 1.8.0 which is the latest version.

Comment: Debian is now not what it was...Most packages are depreciated for years...:( My own feeling is that it dies slowly...[cries] Regarding source code for `install_fastcgi.sh` : it raised `Nginx not found` if directory `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` cannot be found... https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/blob/master/hhvm/deb/skeleton/usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh Maybe you can adjust this manually

Comment: You can try rolling your own nginx deb with jordansissel's fpm.

Comment: I would stay away from automatic installation scripts... why not take a look at what `install_fastcgi.sh` contains and replicate the process manually, though bypassing the flawed version check ? As a bonus you'll actually know what modifications were made to your system.

Answer (score 0):

The script generally fails when it tries to find this file:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Whis in my case(and I'm assuming yours) does not exist.

All you need to do is add this line to your server block in nginx.conf

```
include /etc/nginx/hhvm.conf;
```

Just make sure the hhvm.conf file is in the /etc/nignx directory.
Retart nginx and hhvm

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hhvm restart
```

Then you should be good to go.
To test it i used this file (phpinfo for hhvm) https://gist.github.com/ck-on/67ca91f0310a695ceb65

Good luck.